# Tailwind CSS hide div on hover not hiding

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a collection of images that appear as cards. The cards have text below them. I am trying to hide the text and show the image only using tailwind v2 with no luck.
My code :

```
<div class="group max-w-sm bg-white m-4 rounded-lg border border-gray-200 shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="rounded-t-lg w-full h-64 object-cover" src="images/care.webp" alt="" />
                        </a>
                        <div class="p-1 visible group-hover:invisible">
                            <p class="visible group-hover:invisible text-center mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">CARE</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of card -->
            
                    <!-- Card -->
                    <div class="group max-w-sm bg-white m-4 rounded-lg border border-gray-200 shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="rounded-t-lg w-full h-64 object-cover" src="images/kindness.jpg" alt="" />
                        </a>
                        <div class="p-1 invisible group-hover:visible">
                            <p class="invisible group-hover:visible text-center mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">KINDNESS</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Any recommendations/advise on what i am doing wrong will be appreciated.
I have referenced [documentation](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/visibility) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71288573/tailwind-css-hide-one-div-and-replace-it-with-another) with no luck

Comment: Are you trying to hide the text on hover? What should be presented before the hover? It's not completely clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: what do you want to do? give details of expected output as well.

Answer (score 0):

in your [documentation](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/visibility) link at the end there is such a code

```
// tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    variants: {
      extend: {
        // ...
       visibility: ['hover', 'focus'],
      }
    }
  }
```

so you have to add these parameters to your `tailwind.config.js` to make it work 
and use these classes `visible hover:invisible`